# CakePHP 2.2.3 - include full URL & referrer in error logs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I have a bunch of PHP warnings in my CakePHP error log. Problem is, I can't figure out what scenarios are causing them, and in CakePHP 2.2.3 at least the URL/referrer is not included in the error log information.

I got this suggestion from another SO question, and added the following code to my AppController's beforeFilter section:

```
    if ($this->name === 'CakeError') 
    { 
        $this->log("URL: ".$this->here); 
        $this->log("Referrer: ".$this->referer());
    }
```

However, this only seems to work if an error has been thrown - it doesn't work if a PHP warning has occurred. How would I adjust this code to catch PHP warnings?

Or is there another way to include the full URL & referrer in the error log?

Comment: You can have a custom ErrorHandling extending the core one and adding some details - see https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Error/MyErrorHandler.php#L131 for an example.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to deal with it? Above is 5 lines of code - if there is a way to extend this to cover warnings and notices rather than just errors that would be splendid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using mark's custom ErrorHandler from the tools plugin:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Error/MyErrorHandler.php#L131